# Rebuild flat json to nested json for treeview plugin

Tags: java, json, nested

From a rest service I receive the following json:

```
    [{
        "number": "59875002030004",
        "level": 1,
        "name": "VALUEOPTIONS - CHANGED NAME",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "51873762550004",
        "level": 2,
        "name": "SEABULK INTERNATIONAL",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "53593295610004",
        "level": 3,
        "name": "NOTRE DAME SECONDARY SCHOOL",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "53593295610024",
        "level": 4,
        "name": "NOTRE DAME SECONDARY SCHOOL",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "57743516530004",
        "level": 3,
        "name": "THE DAILY NEWS",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "55724780540004",
        "level": 4,
        "name": "SEALAND",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "53507720410004",
        "level": 5,
        "name": "BALDWIN TECHNOLOGY",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "58804493340004",
        "level": 3,
        "name": "AUTOMATED BUILDING COMPONENTS",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "53454777630004",
        "level": 2,
        "name": "TECK COMINCO AMERICAN",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "53757520360004",
        "level": 3,
        "name": "THE CONVERTIBLE CASTLE",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "56995879770004",
        "level": 3,
        "name": "INNOVAPOST+",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "58317262690004",
        "level": 4,
        "name": "LYDALL",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "55841724060004",
        "level": 5,
        "name": "PROVIDENT NEW YORK BANCORP",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "57687006340004",
        "level": 5,
        "name": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM",
        "costcenter": "51177"
    }, {
        "number": "57687006340024",
        "level": 6,
        "name": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM",
        "costcenter": "51177"
    }, {
        "number": "57687006340044",
        "level": 6,
        "name": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM",
        "costcenter": "51177"
    }, {
        "number": "57687006340064",
        "level": 6,
        "name": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM",
        "costcenter": "51177"
    }, {
        "number": "57746248440004",
        "level": 5,
        "name": "HAMPSHIRE HOLDINGS CORP",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "57746248440024",
        "level": 6,
        "name": "HAMPSHIRE HOLDINGS CORP",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "57746248440044",
        "level": 6,
        "name": "HAMPSHIRE HOLDINGS CORP",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "58374896490004",
        "level": 4,
        "name": "R.B.C. LIFE INSURANCE",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "59755252870004",
        "level": 2,
        "name": "MERITER HEALTH SERVICES",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }, {
        "number": "51573698010004",
        "level": 3,
        "name": "CATHOLIC ELEMENTARY SCHOOL",
        "costcenter": "53170"
    }, {
        "number": "59788019250004",
        "level": 2,
        "name": "COSMETIC ESSENCE",
        "costcenter": "51181"
    }]
```

Which I need to rebuild for the jonmiles treeview plugin https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview into a nested json similar to:

```
[{
    "custId": "59875002030004",
    "text": "VALUEOPTIONS - CHANGED NAME <span class='label label-default'>59875002030004</span>",
    "tags": ["51181"],
    "nodes": [{
            "custId": "51873762550004",
            "text": "SEABULK INTERNATIONAL <span class='label label-default'>51873762550004</span>",
            "tags": ["53170"],
            "nodes": [{
                    "custId": "53593295610004",
                    "text": "NOTRE DAME SECONDARY SCHOOL <span class='label label-default'>53593295610004</span>",
                    "tags": ["51181"],
                    "state": {
                        "checked": true,
                        "selected": true
                    },
                    "nodes": [{
                        "custId": "53593295610024",
                        "text": "SEABULK INTERNATIONAL <span class='label label-default'>53593295610024</span>",
                        "tags": ["51181"],
                        "state": {
                            "checked": true,
                            "selected": true
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "custId": "57743516530004",
                    "text": "THE DAILY NEWS <span class='label label-default'>57743516530004</span>",
                    "tags": ["53170"],
                    "nodes": [{
                        "custId": "55724780540004",
                        "text": "SEALAND <span class='label label-default'>55724780540004</span>",
                        "tags": ["51181"],
                        "nodes": [{
                            "custId": "53507720410004",
                            "text": "BALDWIN TECHNOLOGY <span class='label label-default'>53507720410004</span>",
                            "tags": ["53170"]
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "custId": "58804493340004",
                    "text": "AUTOMATED BUILDING COMPONENTS <span class='label label-default'>58804493340004</span>",
                    "tags": ["51181"]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "custId": "53454777630004",
            "text": "TECK COMINCO AMERICAN <span class='label label-default'>53454777630004</span>",
            "tags": ["53170"],
            "nodes": [{
                    "custId": "53757520360004",
                    "text": "THE CONVERTIBLE CASTLE <span class='label label-default'>53757520360004</span>",
                    "tags": ["51181"]
                },
                {
                    "custId": "56995879770004",
                    "text": "INNOVAPOST+ <span class='label label-default'>56995879770004</span>",
                    "tags": ["51181"],
                    "nodes": [{
                            "custId": "58317262690004",
                            "text": "LYDALL <span class='label label-default'>58317262690004</span>",
                            "tags": ["53170"],
                            "nodes": [{
                                    "custId": "55841724060004",
                                    "text": "PROVIDENT NEW YORK BANCORP <span class='label label-default'>55841724060004</span>",
                                    "tags": ["51181"]
                                },
                                {
                                    "custId": "57687006340004",
                                    "text": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM <span class='label label-default'>57687006340004</span>",
                                    "tags": ["51177"],
                                    "nodes": [{
                                            "custId": "57687006340024",
                                            "text": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM <span class='label label-default'>57687006340024</span>",
                                            "tags": ["51177"]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "custId": "57687006340044",
                                            "text": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM <span class='label label-default'>57687006340044</span>",
                                            "tags": ["51177"]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "custId": "57687006340064",
                                            "text": "HILLCREST HEALTHCARE SYSTEM <span class='label label-default'>57687006340064</span>",
                                            "tags": ["51177"]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "custId": "57746248440004",
                                    "text": "HAMPSHIRE HOLDINGS CORP <span class='label label-default'>57746248440004</span>",
                                    "tags": ["51181"],
                                    "nodes": [{
                                            "custId": "57746248440024",
                                            "text": "HAMPSHIRE HOLDINGS CORP <span class='label label-default'>57746248440024</span>",
                                            "tags": ["51181"]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "custId": "57746248440044",
                                            "text": "HAMPSHIRE HOLDINGS CORP <span class='label label-default'>57746248440044</span>",
                                            "tags": ["51181"]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "custId": "58374896490004",
                            "text": "R.B.C. LIFE INSURANCE <span class='label label-default'>58374896490004</span>",
                            "tags": ["53170"],
                            "nodes": [{
                                "custId": "51573698010004",
                                "text": "CATHOLIC ELEMENTARY SCHOOL <span class='label label-default'>51573698010004</span>",
                                "tags": ["53170"]
                            }]
                        },
                        {
                            "custId": "59788019250004",
                            "text": "COSMETIC ESSENCE <span class='label label-default'>59788019250004</span>",
                            "tags": ["51181"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "custId": "59755252870004",
            "text": "MERITER HEALTH SERVICES <span class='label label-default'>59755252870004</span>",
            "tags": ["51181"]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Is there any library I can use to unflatten the json or one who has a starting point?